# UISearchBar cancel button no action

Tags: ios, swift, button, searchbar

My `UISearchBar's` cancel button doesn't seem to do anything when clicked. Here is my current code:

```
var searchBar = UISearchBar()
```

and in my `ViewDidLoad`:

```
searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
searchBar.placeholder = "Search City"
searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
searchBar.delegate = self
myTable.tableHeaderView = searchBar
```

Wondering if you can help me figure out what's wrong with my SearchBar and why the cancel button doesn't give any action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Implement SearchBar Delegate**

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder() 
}
```

You can also hide and show `cancel button` as follow:

```
searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
```

Comment: do you know how I can also decrease the width of my search bar? I haven't bene able to figure that one out either